# Rethinkdb: returning more than one object from a query

Tags: python, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python, nosql

I have a table with some rows that look like this:

```
{
  "id": "12345"
  "created_date": Fri May 27 2016 22:06:25 GMT+00:00 ,
  "image": true

} {
  "id": "6789"
  "created_date": Mon May 30 2016 07:48:35 GMT+00:00 ,
  "video": true

}{
  "id": "12345"
  "created_date": Fri May 21 2016 22:06:25 GMT+00:00 ,
  "image": true

} {
  "id": "6789"
  "created_date": Mon May 6 2016 07:48:35 GMT+00:00 ,
  "video": true

}
etc...
```

I would like to return the latest (newest, earliest date) object that has `"video":true`
in addition to this I want return the latest object that has `"image":true`.

**BUT**, I want to do this in one query, since this will ultimately be done on the same table.

Ideally the answer would be:

```
[{
      "id": "12345"
      "created_date": Fri May 27 2016 22:06:25 GMT+00:00 ,
      "image": true

    }, {
      "id": "6789"
      "created_date": Mon May 30 2016 07:48:35 GMT+00:00 ,
      "video": true

    }]
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Is it a **SQL** problem or a **Python** one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine two queries by writing something like `r.expr([query1, query2])` and it should work.